# CakePHP: Rename field name without change the hierarchy

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have this function write in a CakePHP model:

```
public function getPeopleByName($name){
        $this->unbindModel(array('hasMany' => array('OfficePersonTask')));

        $options['fields'] = array("Person.id", "CONCAT(Person.first_name, ' ', Person.last_name) AS full_name");

        return $this->find('all', $options);   
}
```

This gave me the following json:

```
{
   People:[
      {
         0:{
            full_name:"Groucho Marx"
         },
         Person:{
            id:"1"
         }
      },
      {
         0:{
            full_name:"Giovanni Ferretti"
         },
         Person:{
            id:"2"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I would that *full_name* will be part of *Person* group (actually is in a group called 0, all alone). How I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a virtual field in the model rather than a MySQL function in your find.  There are some ways to query for data as you are trying to, but you have to account for data being returned in an indexed array rather than the normal associative.

Comment: I really like the idea of virtual field. Now it's ok ;)
Thank you